# many to many relationship mysql select

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

Let's consider 2 tables "schools"  and "students". Now a student may belong to different schools in his life, and a school have many students. So this is a many to many example. A third table "links" specify the relation between student and school.

Now to query this I do the following:

```
Select sc.sid , -- stands for school id
       st.uid,  -- stands for student id
       sc.sname, -- stands for school name
       st.uname, -- stands for student name
       -- select more data about the student joining other tables for that
from students s
left join links l on l.uid=st.uid  -- l.uid stands for the student id on the links table
left join schools sc on sc.sid=l.sid -- l.sid is the id of the school in the links table
where st.uid=3 -- 3 is an example
```

this query will return duplicate data for the user id if he has more than one school, so to fix this  I added `group by st.uid`, yet I also need the list of school name related to the same user. Is there a way to do it with fixing the query I wrote instead of having 2 queries? So as example I want to have Luci of schools ( X, Y, Z, R, ...) etc

Comment: my solution was a merge of both Ronnis and Spiny Norman. I make it that way `GROUP_CONCAT((concat(sc.sid,'=',sc.sname) SEPARATOR ', ') as school_obj``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregate function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat.

Like this:

```
Select st.uid,  -- stands for student id
       st.uname, -- stands for student name
       GROUP_CONCAT sc.sname SEPARATOR ', ' as school_names,
       -- select more data about the student joining other tables for that
from students s
left join links l on l.uid=st.uid  -- l.uid stands for the student id on the links table
left join schools sc on sc.sid=l.sid -- l.sid is the id of the school in the links table
where st.uid=3 -- 3 is an example
group by st.uid
```

Comment: sounds interesting, I noticed that you added the group by on the wrong position. It should be after the where. yet your methods really helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ugly, but works.

```
select st.uid
      ,st.uname
      ,group_concat(concat(sc.sid,'=',sc.sname)) as example1
      ,group_concat(sc.sid)                      as example2
      ,group_concat(sc.sname)                    as example3
  from students     st
  left join links    l on l.uid  = st.uid
  left join schools sc on sc.sid = l.sid
 where st.uid = 3
 group 
    by st.uid
      ,st.uname;
```

- example_1 gives you value pairs, such as (1=Cambridge,2=Oxford,3=Haganässkolan).
- example_2 contains a csv string of school ids (1,2,3)
- example_3 contains a csv string of school names (Cambridge,Oxford,Haganässkolan)

Comment: i like this part concat(sc.sid,'=',sc.sname)